# Deploying Dijkstra's Algorithm in a Fat Tree Topology!

Tags: routing, network, sdn, ip-forwarding-table

I am trying to deploy Dijkstra's Algorithm for finding the shortest path between switches in a balanced fat-tree topology. The problem is that I do not know what values/unit of weight should be in order to build routing tables for each switch (e.g., link BW capacity, counting the number of switches to a destination, etc.). The issue is that all links have the same bandwidth and the number of switches is identical to transfer packets from host A to host B, refer to the attached figure.

Regards,

[image]

Comment: Is this a homework assignment? "Deploying an algorithm" does not make much sense, you deploy an implementation of an algorithm.

Comment: It is not a homework. Yes, I would like to deploy its implementation.

Comment: *which* implementation?

Comment: It is already written, Dijkstra's Algorithm!

Comment: An algorithm describes how you solve a problem. An implementation is the translation of an algorithm to code which can run on a device. You can't deploy an algorithm. Dijkstra's shortest path algorithm is used in various routing protocols, but you can't "deploy Dijkstra's algorithm".

Comment: Did any answer help you? If so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you could provide and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 2):

Dijkstra's Algorithm doesn't define what the weight should be.   The weight value lets you decide which links are preferred.  If, as you say, all the links have the same bandwidth, then perhaps you don't have a preference.  All weights should be the same.